# Why does h18 error occur when sending the wrong token to the django server hosted in heroku?

Tags: python, django, heroku

I used djangoreostframework-simplejwt to use jwt as the authentication method of my API server, and even when I hosted it to my local server and Pythonanywhere, I was able to confirm that my authentication method was working properly. But after I moved my server to heroku, when I put an expired token or an incorrect token, 503 error occurred, not a response that the token was wrong. So I took a log and got an error message like this.

```
2020-11-19T12:23:08.806190+00:00 heroku[router]: sock=backend at=error code=H18 desc="Server Request Interrupted" method=POST path="/feed/post" host="our domain" request_id=f716d063-ff6a-4be7-a93c-c296909c3a9a fwd="221.168.22.204" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=191ms status=503 bytes=408 protocol=https
```

I wonder if there are such bugs in heroku, django, django-rest-framework or djangoreostframework-simplejwt. If not, is there something wrong with my authentication method? Here's my code.

settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    ],

    'DEFAULT_SCHEMA_CLASS':'rest_framework.schemas.coreapi.AutoSchema',
}
```

views.py

```
class customLoginView (GenericAPIView) :
    serializer_class = customLoginSerializer

    def post (self, request) :
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        
        try :
            user = User.objects.get(email=serializer.data['email'])

        except User.DoesNotExist :
            return Response({'message': ['이메일 또는 비밀번호를 확인해주세요.']}, status=401)

        if user.check_password(raw_password=serializer.data['password']) == False :
            up = serializer.data['password'].upper()

            if user.check_password(raw_password=up) == False :
                down=serializer.data['password'].lower()
                
                if user.check_password(raw_password=down) == False :
                    return Response({'message': ['이메일 또는 비밀번호를 확인해주세요.']}, status=401)

        if not user.is_verified :
            return Response({'message': ['이메일 인증을 먼저 해주세요.']}, status=401)

        if not user.is_active :
            return Response({'message': ['계정이 비활성화 되었습니다. 관리자에게 문의하세요.']}, status=401)

        token = RefreshToken.for_user(user)

        data = {
            'token_type': 'Bearer',
            'access_token': str(token.access_token),
            'expires_at': str((datetime.now() + timedelta(minutes=30)).astimezone().replace(microsecond=0).isoformat()),
            'refresh_token': str(token),
            'refresh_token_expires_at': str((datetime.now() + timedelta(hours=8)).astimezone().replace(microsecond=0).isoformat())
        }

        return Response(data, status=200)
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be problem of gunicorn on heroku [Gunicorn issue discussion](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/840). Switching to waitress helped temporarily for me.